# OpenVPN Access Server: Exclude specific IP addresses

Tags: routing, openvpn

I have setup an [OpenVPN **Access Server**](http://openvpn.net/index.php/access-server/overview.html) (openvpnas) on a Linux box and use the OpenVPN Connect client on Windows.

How I could exclude specific IP addresses (e.g. google.com current ip) from routing through the vpn?

I read about the push route configuration in Community OpenVPN's `server.conf` or `client.ovpn` files, but I think **OpenVPN Access Server** doesn't use them.

Comment: You do know that the IP addresses for the google.com might change from time to time, right?

Comment: Excluding IP addresses from VPN doesn't work in the long run. You should include only those addresses that need to be routed via VPN.